# Get a CheckBox in Word using OpenXML

Tags: c#, openxml, office-2010, wordprocessingml

How does one get a handle to a CheckBox control that's embedded in a Word document using OpenXML?

You would think that either Paragraph.ControlPropertiesPart or Paragraph.Descendents() would achieve something but in every single case I get a null type returned.

I can traverse down the document tree using the actual XML structure, but this seems cumbersome.

Suggestions welcome.

Comment: Are you using a Check Box Content Control?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The code below shows how to enumerate all checkboxes in a word document by
using the `Decendants<CheckBox>()` method on the docuement's body.

```
using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open("c:\\temp\\checkbox.docx", true))
{
  foreach (CheckBox cb in doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<CheckBox>())
  {
    Console.Out.WriteLine(cb.LocalName);

    FormFieldName cbName = cb.Parent.ChildElements.First<FormFieldName>();
    Console.Out.WriteLine(cbName.Val);

    DefaultCheckBoxFormFieldState defaultState = cb.GetFirstChild<DefaultCheckBoxFormFieldState>();
    Checked state = cb.GetFirstChild<Checked>();

    Console.Out.WriteLine(defaultState.Val.ToString());

    if (state.Val == null) // In case checkbox is checked the val attribute is null
    {
      Console.Out.WriteLine("CHECKED");
    }
    else
    {
      Console.Out.WriteLine(state.Val.ToString());
    }
  }
}
```

To determine the name of a given checkbox input element you have to access the
`Parent` property of the `CheckBox` instance and then search for the `FormFieldName` element (to assign a name to a checkbox use the Properties Dialog in Microsoft Word).

The `DefaultCheckBoxFormFieldState` `Val` property holds the default state for the checkbox.
Furthermore the `Val` property of the `Checked` element holds the actual checked state
of the `CheckBox` instance. Note, for Microsoft Word 2007 the Val property is `null` if
the checkbox is checked.

**BEGIN EDIT**

I'd like to extend my answer. In fact, there are two kinds of checkbox controls on the MS Word developer tab - a legacy checkbox and an ActiveX control checkbox. The code shown above can be used to enumerte legacy checkboxes in a word document (see this [article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/create-forms-that-users-complete-or-print-in-word-HA010030746.aspx) on how to create a legacy checkbox).

As far as I know, you can't use the OpenXML SDK to get/set values for an ActiveX checkbox.
However you can enumerate ActiveX controls using the following code:

```
foreach (Control ctrl in doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Control>())
{
   Console.Out.WriteLine(ctrl.Id);
   Console.Out.WriteLine(ctrl.Name);
   Console.Out.WriteLine(ctrl.ShapeId);
}
```

To determine whether or not a given `Control` is a checkbox you have to ckeck the class ID of the `Control`. The class ID of a checkbox is `{8BD21D40-EC42-11CE-9E0D-00AA006002F3}`.
Here is a code sample to get the class ID (I don't know if there is an easier way...):

```
OpenXmlPart part = doc.MainDocumentPart.GetPartById(ctrl.Id);
OpenXmlReader re = OpenXmlReader.Create(part.GetStream());
re.Read();
OpenXmlElement el = re.LoadCurrentElement();          
if(el.GetAttribute("classid", el.NamespaceUri).Value == "{8BD21D40-EC42-11CE-9E0D-00AA006002F3}")
{
  Console.WriteLine("Checkbox found...");
}
re.Close();
```

**END EDIT**

**EDIT 2**

I didn't realize that there is a new checkbox control in Word 2010 (Thanks to Dennis
 Palmer).

To enumerate those new checkbox controls you can use the following code:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filename, true))
{
   MainDocumentPart mp = doc.MainDocumentPart;

   foreach(SdtContentCheckBox cb in mp.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtContentCheckBox>())
   {         
     if(cb.Checked.Val == "1");
     {
       Console.Out.WriteLine("CHECKED");  
     }           
   }
}
```

**END EDIT 2**

Hope, this helps.

Comment: That's what I would have expected to work, except the three checkboxes I have put in my code are still not being picked up. I can't for the life of me figure out what I've done. Unless there are different types of checkboxes. I've created a sample document and inserted the checkboxes from the Controls group in the Developer tab.

Comment: @Phil.Wheeler: Do you use the ActiveX Checkbox or the legacy checkbox control? Note, the code above only works with the legacy checkbox.

Comment: I'd say it was the ActiveX control. It's a brand new document created for purpose and the checkbox was added through the Developer tab in Word 2010. I don't see how the legacy control would have even appeared in the equation.

Comment: @Phil.Wheeler: I've updated my answer. In fact, there are two kinds of checkboxes - legacy checkboxes and ActiveX control checkboxes. Please see my answer above on how to enumerate ActiveX checkboxes.

Comment: Thanks. Having thought to actually open my eyes and look at the tab group, I found the "Legacy Tools" control group under a smart button (of sorts) at the lower right of the standard group of controls.

Comment: Word 2010 adds a brand new type of Check Box -- the Check Box Content Control. I didn't think content controls were ActiveX and it's definitely not *legacy*.

Comment: @DennisPalmer: Thank you! I didn't realize that there is a new checkbox control in Word2010. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Phil.Wheeler: I've updated my answer to show how to enumerate the new checkbox controls in Word2010. So, there are three kinds of checkboxes: Legacy, ActiveX and Content Checkboxes.

Comment: What namespace do you find the StdContentCheckBox control in?

Comment: @Phil.Wheeler: There was a typo in my answer. The name of the class is SdtContentCheckBox. The namespace is DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Office2010.Word.

Comment: Gah! Of course it is. Never even thought about that despite mis-typing it numerous times already.