# OpenXML: How to get a list of checked check-boxes in Excel sheet?

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am trying to read an Excel document to get a list of checked check-boxes.

- I have found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336350/get-a-checkbox-in-word-using-openxml) for locating Checkboxes in Word
  documents using OpenXML, but not able to reuse this for Checkboxes in
  Excel.  It seems that the [CheckBox Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.checkbox(v=office.14).aspx) is reserved for
  WordProcessing documents and not Excel.

Code below shows a list of all checkboxes, but no matter what I do, I am not able to access their value.  ***Any ideas?***

### C# Code:

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(@"C:\test.xlsx", false))
{
    WorkbookPart workBookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;

    foreach (Sheet s in workBookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>())
    {
        if (s.Name.ToString().Equals("Sheet1"))
        {
            WorksheetPart wsPart = workBookPart.GetPartById(s.Id) as WorksheetPart;              

            foreach (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Control cb in wsPart.Worksheet.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Control>())
            {
                if (cb.Name.ToString().IndexOf("CheckBox") > -1)
                {
                    textBox1.AppendText(cb.Name + "\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### UPDATE:

It turns out, we are using Active X controls. The following code is able to locate checkboxes correctly, a very very low performing solution, but not using OpenXML:

```
var xlApp = new Excel.Application();
var xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(xlFileName);
var xlSheet = xlWorkbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"] as Excel.Worksheet;

StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder();

try
{
    Excel.OLEObjects oleObjects = xlSheet.OLEObjects() as Excel.OLEObjects;

    foreach (Excel.OLEObject item in oleObjects)
    {
        if (item.progID == "Forms.CheckBox.1")
        {
            VBE.CheckBox xlCB = item.Object as VBE.CheckBox;

            if (xlCB.get_Value())
                x.Append(item.Name + ": checked");
            else
                x.Append(item.Name + ": not checked");

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlCB); xlCB = null;
        }

    }

    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oleObjects); oleObjects = null;
}
catch (Exception ex){ }

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlSheet); xlSheet = null;
xlWorkbook.Close(false, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook); xlWorkbook = null;         

if (xlApp != null)
    xlApp.Quit();

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
xlApp = null;
```

**Any further suggestions?**

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using **Form Controls CheckBox** something in these lines should help:

```
//s is the Sheet
WorksheetPart wsPart = workBookPart.GetPartById(s.Id) as WorksheetPart;

foreach (var control in wsPart.ControlPropertiesParts)
{
    string ctrlId = wsPart.GetIdOfPart(control);
    Console.Write("Control Id: {0}", ctrlId);
    if (control.FormControlProperties.Checked != null)
        Console.Write("Checked");
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Unlike MS Word, Excel has **Form Controls** and **Active X Controls**. You can read about the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15479852/3110695)

Comment: I am using Active X Controls, above code did not locate any Controls. At this point I know I can just use MS Interop to find the checkboxes. However, could we do this via OpenXML?