# Updating checkbox in a word without Microsoft Office

Tags: c#, ms-word

How do I check/uncheck an MSWord checkbox without using Microsoft Office?

Already I have written code using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` and it is working fine.

But the moment I deployed this code to the server, I noticed "Microsoft Office" was not in the server.

So, I started googling about "OpenXML" but found we can't update MSWord checkbox using "OpenXML".

Can anyone have any idea how to overcome this problem?

Comment: Try [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336350/get-a-checkbox-in-word-using-openxml)

Comment: As you'll read in the COMMENTS to the link posted by MY Mnu, Word has at least three different kinds of checkbox. Whether you can edit a checkbox using OpenXML depends purely on which of the three the document contains. ActiveX type is not accessible, the form field (legacy) and content control types should be. I recommend you use the Content Control for this.

Comment: Hi Cindy.. Thanks for your reply..

Comment: please can you clarify me the below items.

1) do we can check/uncheck Content Control checkbox[can we update the checkbox]?

2) we also need Radio button, do we have Radio button in Content Controls[As per I checked "Radio button" was not there in content controls]?

3) If these things are not possible with the Content Control, Is there any other way through which we can achieve those task.

Like: can we do this using VBA Macro?

Thanks in Advance